# My article that was cited in a book does not appear on google scholar

Tags: books, google-scholar

The name of my article is *Hominin interbreeding and the evolution of human variation* and it is referenced in the book "Ingenious: The Unintended Cost of Human Innovation" But this does not appear on my google scholar citations page.

https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=CfyzDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA304&dq=Ingenious:+The+Unintended+Cost+of+Human+Innovation+hominin+interbreeding+and+the+evolution+of+human+variation&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBgNSLx9DlAhWYd94KHdhtAKUQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=Ingenious%3A%20The%20Unintended%20Cost%20of%20Human%20Innovation%20hominin%20interbreeding%20and%20the%20evolution%20of%20human%20variation&f=false

I am not familiar with how google scholar works, so I did send a message to them through the google scholar contact form.

Does it generally take a lot of time for google scholar to pick up citations from books? or is there another reason for this?

Comment: Welcome to academia.SE. Google scholar is generally not fast, so you should add some time information to the question.

Answer (score 1):

They do not accept emails and there is no customer service. To get your article to appear, host it as a PDF on a university server, or if not available, at a repository like the Open Science Framework (osf.io). Google will scrape it within a few days, generally. You can also add articles manually to a Google Scholar profile. Also, see many similar posts in this forum: [Why do papers sometimes appear unlinked in Google Scholar?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17783/why-do-papers-sometimes-appear-unlinked-in-google-scholar?rq=1)